# Cannot add unit test assembly to VS2013 project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reflection

I wish to use the CustomAttibutes collection on the types in a loaded assembly to find those types tagged with the MS-defined TestClassAttribute. I'm using VS2013 Pro (which includes unit testing, and my tests do run), and the attribute in question is defined in Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll. However I can't seem to add a reference to the assembly even though the dll is listed (as an 'extension' in the Add References dialog in VS2013. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the test project already referencing the project you want to add the reference to? Basically, are you trying to create a circular reference?

Comment: No it isn't already referenced, and this isn't a test project per se, it's a simple console app that I am writing to convert old-style vsmdi files to new style playlists. Actually I have overcome the problem by locating the actual dll and using 'Browse' to reference it. Trying to reference it by selecting it from the Add Reference>Assemblies>Extensions (where it is listed) pane just doesn't work. Sounds like a VS2013 bug if you ask me.